# How to structure folder with namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have the project directory like:

```
proj
--src
--include
  --image_processing
    --kernel.hpp
  --image_processing.hpp
```

In `image_processing.hpp`, I have:

```
namespace ImageProcessing{
  class Kernel;
}
```

and in `kernel.hpp`, I have:

```
#include "image_processing.hpp"

class ImageProcessing::Kernel {
  //...
}
```

Is this the correct/suggested folder structure for namespace definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am used to is to use a folder for each namespace (like diving the source in blocks), both including src and include. Something like.

```
proj
-- imageprocessing
    --src
    --include
        --kernel.hpp
        --image_processing.hpp
-- another namespace folder
....
```

However I think you can do the way you prefer.